# Using Devise to set up referrals issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies, devise

I am running devise to handle user authentication, I am wondering if any of you have experience in setting one up with devise?

I found [this small post](http://danvoell.com/dev/2013/06/simple-affiliate-and-referral-tracking-with-devise-in-rails-with-a-hint-of-cookies-and-session-variables/) which is nice but am a bit confused as to how this line works:

```
def capture_referal
  session[:referral] = params[:referral] if params[:referral]
end
```

I can't see in that example where I am meant to input in the `params[:referral]` ?

Also this seems kind of simple, is the referral token going to be the referral code the user sets e.g `RAILSDEVISE` or will it be the entire URL `x.com?ref=RAILSDEVISE`?

If anyone has a github of a rails referral program i'd love to check it out(:

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
#app\controllers\application_controller.rb
def capture_referal
  session[:referral] = params[:referral] if params[:referral]
 end
```

add a hidden field to your registrations view:

```
#app\views\devise\registrations\new.html.erb
<%= f.hidden_field :referral_code, value: session[:referral] %>
```

To add `:referral_code` as a permitted parameter, create the following file:

```
#app\controllers\users\registrations_controller.rb
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

 protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:referral_code])
  end
end
```

And finally update your route to:

```
#config\routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

That's it, you do not need to add `params[:referral]` anywhere else.

And to answer your last question if your referral link is `x.com?referral=sdewddf`, only `sdewddf` will be saved in the `:referral_code` field